# add time field to kibana index results in No data found

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am new to elasticsearch and Kibana. I have just downloaded the latest versions and trying to work on logstash example. As described in this link 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-define-index.html I added the logstash* index with "Index contains time-based events" checked and choose @timestamp as the time field name. When I go to discover your data I do not see anything and I get No results found. If I create the index in Kibana without checking the time-based checkbox I can see the data. Any idea why? I have java 1.8.0_111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So actually there is data, its just that the data is old and the time-stamps in the data are around May 2015. When you create a new index the default time range that is selected is I think last 15 minutes which couldn't find that data as the data in that tutorial is old.

So try these steps.
when you go to `discover`, Click Time Picker in the Kibana toolbar

[image]

Now click on `Absolute` and select a date range from Jan 2015 or something

[image]

this should load your results.